# Bed bugs to be killed with 15 KW (70 amp) saunas and 6 box fans...What wire to use?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I bought a rental house with bed bugs.  I want to hook up 2x 15kw saunas and 6 box fans (1100 CFM) to move the hot air.  The saunas will heat the house up to 120 F and hold it at that temp for at least 1 hour which will kill the bed bugs, roaches and anything else (boil the goldfish? No, they will be gone... the house is empty).

I plan to hook up each 70 amp sauna directly to the breaker box with 70(?) amp breakers, removing other breakers to make space.  The box will be dedicated to those 2 saunas and 6 fans for 10 hours.

If the wire must travel 60 feet from box to sauna, what wire do I need to be safe?

Comment: If the saunas use 15kW @ 240v, that's 62.5 amps of continuous power.  If they are going to pull that for a extended period (and it sounds like they are), the breakers and wiring need to be rated for at least 80 amps due to the "80% De-rating rule".

Comment: What are the fans going to be plugged into?  Are the Saunas purely 240v or do they need three wires (120v and 240v)?

Comment: Not a very impressive amount of heat, actually. Just over 50Kbtu/hr each. You may well have trouble getting to 120F on the whole house with that unless it's a warm day. Much larger BTU/Hr fuel burning construction heaters are available, sometimes for rent, that might work better for getting the job done. I've spent some time with a 11KW kiln, which probably got the room it was in that hot, but not much beyond that room...

Comment: Does it really only take 120F to kill bed bugs and roaches? That seems oddly low to me.

Comment: If you hold it there for long enough (I think at least 90 minutes for eggs), then yes.  But I'd be worried that 120 in the middle of the room would be much less than that up against a wall or floor.  They would be a heat sink and the air isn't going to move as fast right up against the walls.  Also, big furniture may take a long time to come up to that 120.

Comment: If you are planning on drawing 125 amps continuously you should also be aware that the utility transformer to your house may not be sufficiently large to allow this.  10-15KVA is common for a single transformer serving a small house.  If you have a 10KVA transformer, then you are proposing to draw triple the nameplate for over 1 hour.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk, I had to look it up too, and there's companies that do this as a service.  I didn't research enough to see _how_ the do it, but they list 120 as the kill temperature (for at least an hour).  Search for "kill bed bug heat".

Comment: It may be less expensive to buy a huge sack of diatomaceous earth, dust the entire house, twice in a day (to ensure coverage) and leave it for 48 hours, then clean up.

Comment: I'd be extremely cautious about running any fuel-powered heater in that hot an environment. I doubt the designers ever considered running them in 120F+ ambient. All sorts of entertaining (for the fire department) failures might occur, not the least of which would be the propane tank venting.

Comment: @Griscom - excellent point.  It seems some professional exterminators have been caught by this.  From "nbcnewyork.com" July 3, 2013:  "After the Edmonton condominium building burned, Canadian fire investigators issued a $10,000 fine to Calgary-based pest control company Bed Bug Task Force. The exterminators were found to have used propane heaters against fire code. The owners of the apartment building are now suing Bed Bug Task Force for $3.5 million in damages."

Answer (score -1):

Ok so the heat pump I just bought is rated 5 ton or 60,000 btus that converts to 16 kW. So you have the equivalent of 120,000 btus. Depending on the size of the house, the insulation quality, and the temperature outside you may not be able to get the house up to 120 degrees. You would be better off with 3 or 4 100,000 BTU propane heaters. Preferably 4. Then you don't have to worry about overloading the electrical service. Which you didn't say what size it is, but if it is an older house, as is the case with most rental property, then it is a 100 amp service and will not hold two 60 amp continuous loads anyway. Turn the furnace on full blast and then boost it with the propane heaters.